# Windows 10 and Python: Change Wallpaper fill background color and make the wallpaper centered

Tags: python, windows, wallpaper

I figured out that you can change the wallpaper in Python with

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, wallpaper_path ,0)
```

How can you make that image centered and change the fill color (if the image is smaller than the screen size)?

Something like this makes the background centered with some delay, but the background color doesn't change instantly (maybe with a reboot)

```
import winreg

def set_reg(reg_path, name, value):
    try:
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path)
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path, 0, 
                                       winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

set_reg(r"Control Panel\Colors","Background", '0 0 0')

set_reg(r"Control Panel\Desktop","WallpaperStyle", "0")
set_reg(r"Control Panel\Desktop","TileWallpaper", "0")
```

Is there any solution that applies instantly?

Answer (score 0):

Took some information from [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/22/pywin32-how-to-set-desktop-background/) and created a solution

```
import ctypes
import winreg


def set_reg(reg_path, name, value):
    try:
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path)
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path, 0,
                                      winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False


set_reg(r"Control Panel\Colors", "Background", '0 0 0')

set_reg(r"Control Panel\Desktop", "WallpaperStyle", "6")
set_reg(r"Control Panel\Desktop", "TileWallpaper", "1")
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, r"YOUR_PATH", 1+2)
```

You basically just needed to add the 1+2 in order to have it read the reg key when running